# Appending to list within key value list in compact Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am looking to assess if there is a better method to append to a list within a list within a dictionary.

I have many different packets and associated strings to search for in a huge text file.  Associated to each string is a value I want to store in a list so that I can perform calculations like average/max/min.

Due to the packet variations and associated strings for each packet I was looking to keep a dictionary entry to a single line.  So I would have a Key as the packet ID and the value as a list of elements, see below

```
mycompactdict={
    "packetID_001":[12,15,'ID MATCH',[['search_string',[]  ],['search_string2',[]  ]]]
    "packetID_002":[...etc]
}
```

The 12,15 ints are references I use later in Excel plotting. The 'ID_MATCH' entry is my first check to see if the packet ID matches the file object. The 'search_string' references are the strings I am looking for and the blank lists next to them is where I hope to drop the values associated to each search string after splitting the line in the text file.

Now I may be biting off more than Python can chew...  I realize there is a list within a list within a list within a list within a dict!

Here's a start of my code...

```
def process_data(file_object):
    split_data = file_object.split('\n')
    for key in mycompactdict:
        if mycompactdict[key][2] in file_object:
            for line in split_data:
                if item[0] for item in mycompactdict[key][3] in line:
                    value = line.split('=', 1)
                    value.strip()
                    print value
```

and then append the stripped value to mycompactdict[key][6]item[1]

Am I on the wrong approach which will cause performance problems later on, and is there a cleaner alternative?

Below is an example of the file_object in the for of a unicode block of text, there are both matching and differing packet IDs I need to account for.

```
14:27:42.0  ID_21 <<(ID_MATCH)
Type = 4
Fr = 2
search_string1 = -12
search_string2 = 1242
```

Comment: Any reasons you are not using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrames for this?

Comment: Can you post a few sample lines from `file_object`? Also, you're indexing to `6` in `mycompactdict[key]` but it only goes from 0 to 3.

Comment: Hi mike.k I have added an example of the file_object I work with, there are both similar and alternative file_objects I need to deal with, but are of a similar structure

Comment: I encourage you to consider @Sardathrion's suggestion.

Comment: In fact it's not entirely clear from your file_object contents - what is it that you are trying to achieve. I assume you are trying to read a text file - whose lines are like this? And the way you'd manage that is through updating a dict? I believe - you might have to maintain a state machine - of some sorts if you are reading a huge file as - `file_object.split('\n')` is going to give you a huge list. The data isn't enough to justify whether you should use 'pandas' and yes. A more clear problem statement might help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to re-invent the wheel were I in your position. Thus, I would use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It has something called [DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) that would be a good fit for what you are trying to do.  In addition, you can [export those into exel spread sheets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-excel). Have a look at the [10min introduction](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).